# Beanstalk + CodePipeline Keep some directories in instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have a Wordpress repository that I'm deploying to a Beanstalk application through the CodePipeline + Github.
When the CodePipeline releases any changes on the `master` branch, the deployment process starts, but it replaces the whole project and I'd like to keep some directories in the instance such as `uploads/` and `plugins/`.
Is there a way to keep them when the Deployment stage starts?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using the S3 service instead.

1. Setup a S3 bucket
2. Install this plugin https://github.com/humanmade/S3-Uploads
3. The plugin contains instructions to perform the migration
4. Done, all files will be uploaded to S3 instead and the Pipeline will never replace it.